# pythonでネストされた関数をもったクラスを継承した際のオーバーライドの仕方

Tags: python

```
class name1(object):

    def method1(self):

       def method2():
           print 'Hi!'

       method2()

class name2(name1):

    method2のprint 'Hi'をprint 'Hello'にする記述
```

どのように書けばよいかご指南ください。

Answer (score 3):

`method1` 自体を再実装してください。

`method2` は `method1` のコードの一部なので、「クラスを継承して、親クラスの関数のコードを数行だけ書き換えたい」のであれば、「親クラスの関数全部を再実装する」必要があります。

「親クラスの関数」がサブクラスで再利用できそうなコードを持ってしまっているのであれば、複数のメソッドやモジュールグローバルな関数に分割して、それを再利用することを検討してください。 [Flat is better then nested.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) です。

Answer (score 0):

以下の様になりますが、見ての通りの有様ですのでお勧めはしません。

**replace_inner_func.py**

```
import new

class name1(object):
  def method1(self):
     def method2():
       print 'Hi!'
     method2()

class name2(name1):
  def __init__(self):
    def method2():
      print 'Hello!'

    m1 = self.method1
    m1_code = m1.func_code
    new_method = (None, method2.func_code)
    self.method1 = new.instancemethod(
      new.function(
        new.code(
          m1_code.co_argcount, m1_code.co_nlocals, m1_code.co_stacksize,
          m1_code.co_flags, m1_code.co_code, new_method, m1_code.co_names,
          m1_code.co_varnames, m1_code.co_filename, m1_code.co_name,
          m1_code.co_firstlineno, m1_code.co_lnotab),
        globals()),
      self, self.__class__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  n1 = name1()
  n2 = name2()
  n1.method1()
  n2.method1()
```